# How to loop through a Firebase datasnapshot sub childrens? Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I have a DataSnapshot JSON object :

```
{fridge2: true, fridge1: true} //data pulled from a real time firebase database
```

I have to put `fridge2` and `fridge1` in a list like this:

```
List<String> fridges;
```

My attempt:

```
DataSnapshot fridgesDs = snapshot.value['fridges'];

    for (var fridge in fridgesDs) {
      if (fridge.value) {
        fridges.add(fridge.key);
      }
    }
```

Gives me this error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it. I used to  `print(fridgesDs.runtimeType);` to get the type of variable returned by firebase. it is actually a HashMap: `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` 
The casted the returned value into a **Map**. Finally, I used forEach to loop through the map. Here is the final version:

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> fridgesDs = snapshot.value['fridges'];
//    print(fridgesDs.runtimeType);
    fridgesDs.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value) {
        fridges.add(key);
      }
    });
```