# Flutter: The method forEach isn't defined for the class DataSnapshot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I need to iterate a node in a `DatabaseReference` in firebase. But it is wired that there is no `forEach` function in `DataSnapshot` that is in `firebase_database` library!

I also tried to use `DataSnapshot` object that is in `firebase` library (that has a forEach function in it) but I got a error:

```
[dart] The argument type '(DataSnapshot) → List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(DataSnapshot) → FutureOr<dynamic>'.
```

And here is my code:

```
getAccountsList() {
  return firebaseDbService.getAccounts().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    var list = [];
    snapshot.forEach((DataSnapshot account) => list.add({
      'id': snapshot.key,
      'name': snapshot.child('name').val(),
    }));
    return list;
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a Firebase datasnapshot sub childrens? Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696564/how-to-loop-through-a-firebase-datasnapshot-sub-childrens-flutter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unclear what you are trying to do in your code, both `child(String path)` and `val()` do not exist in the class `DataSnapshot`, you can check here:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/event.dart#L27

Also you cannot loop like this:

```
for( var values in snapshot.value){
 print("Connected to second database and read ${values}");
}
```

since you will get the following error:

[image]

which means also you cannot use `forEach()` on the snapshot to iterate.

---

Let's say you have this database, and you want to get the `names`:

```
user
  randomId
     name: John
  randomId
     name: Peter
```

You need to do the following:

```
_db=FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("user");
_db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
   Map<dynamic, dynamic> values=snapshot.value;
   print(values.toString());
     values.forEach((k,v) {
        print(k);
        print(v["name"]);
     });
 });
```

Here the reference points toward the node `users`, since `snapshot.value` is of type `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` then you are able to do this `Map<dynamic, dynamic> values=snapshot.value;`.

Then you loop inside the `map` using [`forEach()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) to be able to get the keys and values, you will get the following output:

[image: output]

This line `I/flutter ( 2799): {-LItvfNi19tptjdCbHc3: {name: peter}, -LItvfNi19tptjdCbHc1: {name: john}}` is the output of `print(values.toString());`

Both the following lines:

```
I/flutter ( 2799): -LItvfNi19tptjdCbHc3
I/flutter ( 2799): -LItvfNi19tptjdCbHc1
```

are the output of `print(k);`

The other two lines are the output of `print(v["name"]);`

To add the `names` into a list do the following inside the `forEach()`:

```
list.add(v["name"]);
    print(list);
```