# Flutter: Get Firebase Database reference child all data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I have a firebase database child which content is like below:

[image]

How to retrieve this in flutter?

My Current code:

```
static Future<Query> queryUsers() async{
return FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("zoom_users")
    .orderByChild('name');
}

queryUsers().then((query){
  query.once().then((snapshot){
    //Now how to retrive this snapshot? It's value data giving a json
  });
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To retrieve the data try the following:

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("zoom_users");
db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
     values.forEach((key,values) {
      print(values["name"]);
    });
 });
```

Here first you add the reference at child `zoom_users`, then since value returns `data['value']` you are able to assign it to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` and then you loop inside the map using `forEach` and retrieve the values, example `name`.

Check this:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html

[Flutter: The method forEach isn't defined for the class DataSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759155/flutter-the-method-foreach-isnt-defined-for-the-class-datasnapshot/51762392#51762392)

Answer (score 3):

```
  query.once().then((snapshot){
    var result = data.value.values as Iterable;
    for(var item in result) {
      print(item);
    }
  });
```

or with `async` that you already use

```
  var snapshot = await query.once();
  var result = snapshot.value.values as Iterable;
  for(var item in result) {
    print(item);
  }
```