# What is the method to show data from a list on screen in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I stored some data from firestore instance in a list and now I want to display the data on my screen.

When I print my list in terminal, I see this:

```
I/flutter (11351): [{num: 100, title: This is test 2}]
```

I defined a list like this:

```
var list = new List();
```

I am fetching data on a click of button.

```
RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var documentReference = await Firestore.instance.collection('insults').document('vv4YjpyRFFEknbCyC9o7');
                  documentReference.get().then((documentSnapshot){
                    setState(() {
                      list.add(documentSnapshot.data);
                    });
                    print(list);

                  }) ;
                },
                child: Text('Press me'),
              ),
```

Please guide me a little. I just started learning flutter.

I do not want to loop through document but I want to store it in a list using a suitable method.

Comment: why are you using a list to store only 1 map ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through a Firebase datasnapshot sub childrens? Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696564/how-to-loop-through-a-firebase-datasnapshot-sub-childrens-flutter)

Comment: @LoVe This is just a test. I can add more anyway.

Comment: @Sidak I want to show data via a flutter widget on screen. I have it in my list and now I want to show on screen.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thank you. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to show a list, since you are only retrieving data under one document, if you want to show the retrieved data, then you can do the following:

First create an instance variable under your `State`:

```
Map<String, dynamic> retrievedData = Map<String, dynamic>();
```

Then inside `setState` assign the data to `retrievedData`:

```
RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var documentReference = await Firestore.instance.collection('insults').document('vv4YjpyRFFEknbCyC9o7');
                  documentReference.get().then((documentSnapshot){
                    setState(() {
                      retrieveData = documentSnapshot.data;
                    });
                  }) ;
                },
                child: Text('Press me'),
              ),
```

Inside the `build` method you can have a `Column` with multiple `children` for example:

```
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
               retrievedData["title"] ?? "",
            ),
             Text(
              retrievedData["num"] ?? "",
            ), 
          ],
```

When clicking the button, `setState` will call the build method and you will have your data on the screen.